# Parsing a subset of JSON in Java using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

Given a Json, is it possible to use Jackson to only parse out a section of the message?
Say that the data I'm interested in is buried in a deep hierarchy of fields and I simply do not care about creating DTO classes for each and every class.

Given a very simplified scenario I'd like to model the Telephone class without knowing anything about the structure before it:

```
...{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName" : "doe",
  "age"      : 26,
  "address"  : {
    "streetAddress": "naist street",
    "city"         : "Nara",
    "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type"  : "iPhone",
      "number": "0123-4567-8888"
    },
    {
      "type"  : "home",
      "number": "0123-4567-8910"
    }
  ]
}....
```

I'm thinking something in the terms of using json-path together with deserializing just the parts I'm interested of. Some pseudo:

```
List<Telephone> phoneNrs = parse(".my.deep.structure.persons.phoneNumbers", List<Telephone.class>);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode json = mapper.readTree("... your JSON ...");
```

Using the `JsonNode` object you can then call `get("my").get("deep").get("structure")` to get the node you want.

Once you got your hands on that node, a simple call to `mapper.treeToValue(myDeepJsonNode, Telephone[].class)` will get you your array of`Telephone`. You can get a list using a `TypeReference` as well.

To get to your deep `JsonNode` you can also use the `findValue` and `findPath` methods.

The Javadoc:
https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks everyone else as well for the quick and thorough replies.

Comment: I don't like this solution. Jackson should support only partially defined model classes for the given JSON strings.

Comment: @Jurass I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Note that you can always deserialize to maps if the structure is highly flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JsonPath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) library. With this library you can map your JsonPath output directly into POJO's.

Pseudo:

```
List<Telephone> phoneNrs = JsonPath.parse(json).read("$.my.deep.structure.persons.phoneNumbers", List.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible the way you have mentioned in the Pseudo code. "phoneNumbers" is a key and value returned can be passed on to Jackson deserialiying.

If the response is an array of maps then you can iterate through each one of them and use the `yourResponseAsJSONObject.get('phoneNumbers')` method to get the value and pass it on to Jackson

or use JsonPath as mentioned by @dimas

Answer (score 0):

To do this efficiently with Jackson, use the Streaming API via the JsonParser class (http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.html).

This approach will allocate no additional memory and will not incur the cost of deserializing values for all of the skipped data. Since the code will be much longer and more difficult to read than using Jackson's ObjectMapper, only do this if profiling shows unacceptable GC activity or CPU usage during parsing.

You can skip all of the nodes that you are uninterested in until you hit the "phoneNumbers" key. Then you can call the `readValueAs` function to deserialize the array of phone number dictionaries like so `readValueAs(new TypeReference<MyPhoneNumberType[]>())`.

See also:

- a tutorial on reading and writing with JsonParser: http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2009/01/entry_132.html
- The main documentation: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core