# Spring Resttemplate: Parsing using @JsonIgnore causes values to be null

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, resttemplate

So, I am using Spring Boot 1.5.3 and am trying to a part  of the following Json - - namely `AccountId` and `Username`- (actually, it is an oData v2 interface getting from a SAP Netweaver instance) into a class using restTemplate.exchange:

```
{  
   "d":{  
      "__metadata":{  
         "id":"...",
         "uri":"...",
         "type":"...."
      },
      "AccountID":"0100000001",
      "Username":"test@test.com",
      "Partners":{  
         "__deferred":{  
            "uri":"Navigationproperty"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

My class is set up like this, because for a start I only want to get the account id and name:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class PortalAccount implements Serializable{

    public PortalAccount() {
    }

    @JsonProperty("AccountID")
    public String accountID;

    @JsonProperty("Username")
    public String username;

    public String getPortalAccountID() {
        return accountID;
    }

    public void setPortalAccountID(String portalAccountID) {
        this.accountID = portalAccountID;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Account{" +
                "accountID='" + accountID + '\'' +
                ", username='" + username +'\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

and here's the way I try to call it:

```
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = this.createHeaders();
        ResponseEntity<String> response;
        response  = restTemplate.exchange(uri,HttpMethod.GET,new HttpEntity<Object>(httpHeaders),String.class);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        PortalAccount acc = mapper.readValue(response.getBody(), PortalAccount.class);
```

I first tried to parse it directly like in the docs using `ResponseEntity<PortalAccount>`, but this just lead to an empty class (accountid = null, username = null), So i tried the way above using `ResponseEntity<String>` to see what I get when just parsing the response into the string representation. That way, I could make sure the json above is correctly returned, which it is.So, the values are definitely there, it has to be a matter of parsing, but I sadly don't get my way around this problem.

I hope you could help me out here!

edit: As one answer mentions, getForObject might work, but this leads for me to other problems, as I have to use basic authentication, so its not really viable.I also tried casing-issues, naming the Variables accountID or AccountID, which did not work out.

Comment: My guess is, the problem is the object "d" in the JSON which wraps AccountId and Username. This would actually translate to a Class named "d" which contains Strings "AccountId" and "Username". For testing purposes, try to name your class "d" instead of PortalAccount.

Comment: Also, try @JsonTypeName("d") on class PortalAccount

Comment: So, yes, getBody() contains the json i added to the question. Now I tried changing class to "d", which results in same behaviour. Also, I tried adding JsonTypeName("d") to the `d`-Class and to the re-refactoerd PortalAccount-Class, without success :/

Comment: Ok, so I probably got it wrong and you have to wrap "d" in another Class, so that you have a class that contains type "d" as property as it is now. Again, for testing purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, Christian Zieglers Comments and Answer is partially right.

You need to make sure your Class Structure can be mapped from the retrieved Json.

So, to make it work, the imho easiest way woud be, instead of creating a wrapper object:

1. Remove your `@JsonIgnoreProperties` Annotation. We'll do this with the object mapper.
2. Then, Add Jacksons [@JsonRootName](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonRootName.html) Property to your class PortalAccount and set the value to `d`. Your class now should only have this one annotation:

`@JsonRootName(value = "d")` like this:

```
@JsonRootName(value = "d")
public class PortalAccount implements Serializable{
    public PortalAccount() {
    }

    @JsonProperty("AccountID")
    public String accountID;

    @JsonProperty("Username")
    public String username;

    ...
}
```

Now, when you call it, you have to set your Objectmapper (assuming jackson 2) to Unwrap your rootElement (and to ignore unknown properties) like this:

```
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

So your whole call would look like this:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = this.createHeaders();
ResponseEntity<String> response;
response  = restTemplate.exchange(uri,HttpMethod.GET,new HttpEntity<Object>(httpHeaders),String.class);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

PortalAccount acc = mapper.readValue(response.getBody(), PortalAccount.class);
```

Important thing here is, as stated above, the @JsonRootName Property, because without it, the `UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE` feature would not work.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that according to your JSON the ObjectMapper would require a class that contains a property of type "d" which contains two properties named "AccountId" and "Username".

So, you essentially need to only parse the content of object "d".

[Parsing a subset of JSON in Java using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36721597/parsing-a-subset-of-json-in-java-using-jackson) describes how it's done.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I think we've been on the right way here. Just accepted the other answer for it has a fully working example and imho the use of `JsonRootName` is way more elegant than creating a wrapper class.

Comment: It sure is. I didn't know about @JsonRootName. Very nice!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the getForObject method instead exchange.

Here is an example:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) 

public class Page { 

    private String name; 
    private String about; 
    private String phone; 
    private String website; 

    public String getName() { 
        return name; 
    } 

    public String getAbout() { 
        return about; 
    } 

    public String getPhone() { 
        return phone; 
    } 

    public String getWebsite() { 
        return website; 
    } 

}  


RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
Page page = restTemplate.getForObject("http://graph.facebook.com/pivotalsoftware", Page.class);
System.out.println("Name:    " + page.getName());
System.out.println("About:   " + page.getAbout());
System.out.println("Phone:   " + page.getPhone());
System.out.println("Website: " + page.getWebsite());
```

Comment: sadly i can't, because I need basic authentication, which lets me run into other problems then. (I hvent found a working example using get/postforobject and basi auth, to be honest).